# In Java, how can I implement a non-generic interface which has methods that use generics using concrete types?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface...

```
public interface ApiClient {
    <T> void updateData(List<T> data);
}
```

and two implementations of that interface...

```
public class Version1ApiClient implements ApiClient {
    public <Version1DataContract> void updateData(List<Version1DataContract> data) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
public class Version2ApiClient implements ApiClient {
    public <Version2DataContract> void updateData(List<Version2DataContract> data) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I get this error in both of the implementations...

> Type parameter 'Version#DataContract' hides visible type 'com.company.package.Version#DataContract'

...where the # is the number for that respective implementation.

What have I done wrong? Also, in this use case the interface cannot have a type parameter on it directly. It can only be on the method.

Comment: What you want is _not possible_ without putting a type parameter on the interface instead of the method.  Sorry, but it's true.  Any class that aims to implement `ApiClient` as it is written must write an implementation of `updateData` that accepts literally any list, not just a list of a particular type.  The only way around that is to add a type parameter to `ApiClient`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't do much that's wrong; but you skipped a naming convention - but that could be hiding a more important misunderstanding

What do you think `<Version1DataContract>` does here?

```
public <Version1DataContract> void updateData(List<Version1DataContract> data) {
    // ...
}
```

Do you think it makes `updateData` work just with `Version1DataContract`, which is a class on your classpath and imported in the source file of your `Version1ApiClient` class? If your answer is yes, then you're mistaken. That code is equivalent to:

```
public <T> void updateData(List<T> data) {
    // ...
}
```

`<Version1DataContract>` is just a weirdly named type variable.

Now, about your question... The problem is that you have declared `<Version1DataContract>` as a type variable on a method, while there is an imported type called `Version1DataContract`, and that is already visible. This is a warning alerting you to potential bugs.

---

To address what seems to be your main issue, if you need `Version1ApiClient` to limit `<T> void updateData(List<T> data);` to `T=Version1DataContract`, you can't do it without changing the interface. You'd have to change your interface and broaden the scope of `T` so that the subclass can "freeze" it:

```
interface ApiClient<T> {
    void updateData(List<T> data);
}

class Version1ApiClient implements ApiClient<Version1DataContract>  {
    public void updateData(List<Version1DataContract> data) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. My main problem was that I assumed I could place a concrete type in place of where the generics were _without_ making the interface itself generic (I primarily work in C#, where this is possible). So, like you said, where I had expected `<Version1DataContract>` would mean it was limited to just that class, I had instead just specified a different, weirdly named type variable that coincided with an imported class.